# Asciidoc custom numeration

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I know you can numerate parts of the doc using kind of dot notation. But is there a way to configure it somehow? I want three dots to stand for 1.1.a for example, not for 1.a.i. How can I do it?

Comment: Is your intended output HTML?

Comment: @9769953 it is. (some more characters to reach that 15 symbols limit)

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [section 21.2 of the asciidoctor user manual](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#numbering-styles), you can use the following:

```
[arabic]
. food
[arabic]
.. fruit
[loweralpha]
... orange
... pear
... apple
.. vegetable
[loweralpha]
... carrot
... cabbage
.. meat
. drinks
[arabic]
.. juice
[loweralpha]
... orange
... pear
... apple
[loweralpha]
.. alcohol
[loweralpha]
... beer
... wine
```

You'll need to set the style after each dedent, hence it makes things a bit unwieldy.

---

I had hoped a simple stylesheet with overriding definitions (for example, for `ol ol { list-style-type: "a" }` could solve this, but it looks like Asciidoctor explicitly adds a class *and* type for each `<ol>` in the HTML output. The former could be changed (though inconveniently) with a user stylesheet, but I think the latter (`type=`) can't be overridden with a stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I had tried this approach and had some problems with it. IIRC using [arabic]  on the "child" list was causing all that hierarchy to break and I had one list instead of parent-child structure. Also, I had to set numbers manually using "start"(e.g. In your example I would set [arabic, start=2] above "vegetable" element) parameter, so it wasn't any better than hardcoding numbers, and, eventually, that's what I did at the end :)

Comment: @НикитаМихайлов That's a bit unclear: you apparently had additional problems, and an additional requirement, not listed in the original question here. That's a bit hard to answer properly then, if people only know part of what you want.

Comment: I think I asked this question earlier than I faced those problems, probably should've updated the question. Anyway, sorry for giving misleading info.

Comment: Ok: problems happen along the way of trying to solve a question. Just leave as it is now, for the occasional other person that has the same question: at least now, question & answer are in accordance.